Socket IO Not Working On Google App Engine
I am using Socket.io for messaging in my React app with a NodeJS / Express API on App Engine. SocketIO is working fine locally, but when I deploy to GAE it fails to connect. I made several attempts to fix this, but with no luck. The GAE instance is on flex with session affinity turned on. I tried multiple ports and enabled port 65080 in my firewall settings. I also set transports to just websocket on my client. I also have CORS enabled for my frontend domain. I have tried both having the same express server as my main app and a separate one. Can anyone help? Many thanks
The error:

My Server side code (Note: I do see Started Socket.IO in my GAE logs, so the socket does listed, but not connection is ever made):
var app1 = require('express')()
const server1 = http.createServer(app1)
const io = require("socket.io")(server1, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://piehost.com","https://app.mysite.co","http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:3002"],
  },
  path: '/mysocket'
})

server1.listen(65080, ()=>{
  console.log('Started SOCKET IO')
})

My Client Side Code:
const URL = 'https://xenon-chain-387522.ew.r.appspot.com:65080';

export const socket = io(URL,{ autoConnect: true, transports: ["websocket"], path: '/mysocket'});

app.yaml:
runtime: nodejs
runtime_config:
    operating_system: "ubuntu22"
    runtime_version: "20"
env: flex
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: xenon-chain-387522:europe-west1:my-instance
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
network:
  session_affinity: true

